# Best way to load static images in Django from root directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am working on a project in Django 2.2 and I am having a problem loading static images. I followed a tutorial that suggests a media directory in the root of the project. After that, I configured settings as suggest as shown below:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The urls.py of the project as shown below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And this is the `base.urls` file that has the pages with the images I am trying to load:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='tedfield-home'),
    path('faqs/', views.faqs, name='tedfield-faqs'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='tedfield-contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='tedfield-about'),
]
```

I am loading static images used by the website. These images are loading well for the home page, but when I navigate to a page like /about, the images fail to load. On checking, the link loaded is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/media/images/brands/brand-2.png` which has the `about` instead of the link: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/brands/brand-2.png` which is the actual link that loads the images. The code that I am using for the html template is:

```
<img src="media/images/icons/area.png" alt="">
```

I have also tried using a static directory on the root folder and placing the image folder in it then loading it using the code below:

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">
```

But it still fail to load the images.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using `my_app/static/my_app` for the images, and it worked. Was following another [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdVuKt_iuSI&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=8) but seems they didn't factor in the trouble with navigating to other pages. But with the above directory, the images are loading fine.